# JSON Reading and printing in screen

Tags: java, json, parsing

I did already some posts about this problem. Since the last I cleaned my code to write the JSON and now looks better and easier to read. The problem is that I dont get to read it.

```
[
{},
{
    "Cliente0": {
        "cif": "45417265",
        "metodopago": "T",
        "codrefcli": "1541121",
        "razonsocial": "Perico de los palotes",
        "num": "964491837",
        "correo": "perico@yahoo.com",
        "direccion": "calle maria la vieja",
        "observaciones": "que pesado"
    }
},
{
    "Empleado0": {
        "apellidos": "Basilio",
        "codempleado": "1",
        "fechaalta": "2018-05-17",
        "numcuenta": "884723877",
        "direccion": "Calle el rio",
        "copiacontrato": "aaa",
        "nombre": "Carlos",
        "dni": "15421451H"
    }
},
{},
{
    "PedidoCliente0": {
        "numped": "454524",
        "fechapedido": "2018-05-09",
        "codcliente": "1541121",
        "cpp": "5132413",
        "enviadoa": "Perico de los palotes",
        "formapago": "Efectivo"
    }
},
{
    "PedidoProveedor0": {
        "numped": "7455112",
        "fechapedido": "2018-05-01",
        "codcliente": "10",
        "cpp": "4555424",
        "enviadoa": "Calle el marino",
        "formapago": "Efectivo"
    }
},
{
    "Producto0": {
        "existencias": "10",
        "crf": "4555424",
        "name": "Limpiador",
        "pvp": "14.99",
        "pve": "8.44",
        "cdp": "10",
        "familia": "Limpieza",
        "desc": "Producto de importacion italiano"
    },
    "Producto1": {
        "existencias": "100",
        "crf": "5132413",
        "name": "Colador",
        "pvp": "18",
        "pve": "15",
        "cdp": "10",
        "familia": "Cocina",
        "desc": "Colador de acero"
    }
},
{},
{
    "Proveedor0": {
        "cif": "10",
        "metodopago": "1",
        "crf": "10",
        "razonsocial": "pene",
        "num": "10",
        "correo": "10",
        "direccion": "10",
        "observaciones": "10"
    },
    "Proveedor1": {
        "cif": "45411",
        "metodopago": "T",
        "crf": "5421452",
        "razonsocial": "Falete",
        "num": "42314",
        "correo": "falete@gmail.com",
        "direccion": "tu casa",
        "observaciones": "Es muy pesado"
    }
}
]
```

I want to read the cif from "Proveedor" but I dont know how to read it. I tried many ways but wasn't succesful. If someone could write the right code please.

Heres the code I tried until now

```
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import org.json.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class parse {
routes router = new routes();
String ruta = router.getruta();
    public parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void parseproductos() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            try(final Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File("N:\\data.json"), "UTF-8" )) {
                final String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                JSONObject rootJSON = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(fileContents);
                JSONArray productos = (JSONArray) rootJSON.get("6");
                int i = 0;
                for(Object projectObj: productos.toArray()) {
                    JSONObject prod = (JSONObject)projectObj;
                    JSONArray datosprod = (JSONArray) prod.get("Producto"+i);

                    for(Object aprodObj: datosprod.toArray()){
                        JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject) aprodObj;
                        System.out.println(dataObj);


                    }
                }

            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

And heres the error I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
at parse.parseproductos(parse.java:24)
at maine.<init>(maine.java:60)
at request$2.actionPerformed(request.java:69)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
...
final String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
//System.out.println("FFFF " + fileContents);
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(fileContents);

JSONObject prov = (JSONObject) arr.get(8);

System.out.println("arr " + arr.toString());

for (int i = 0; i < prov.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject provI = (JSONObject) prov.get("Proveedor" + i);
    System.out.println(provI.get("cif"));
}
...
```

Comment: Id doesn't works.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined
 The method length() is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: But also helped me clarify the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it thanks to NiVeR answer.

```
public void parseproductos() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            try(final Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File("N:\\data.json"), "UTF-8" )) {
                final String fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                JSONArray rootJSON = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(fileContents);
                JSONArray productos = (JSONArray) rootJSON.get(6);
                for (int i = 0; i < productos.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject lpro = (JSONObject) productos.get(i);
                System.out.println(lpro.get("crf"));
                }
                    }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        } 
    }
```

The problem was that I was reading the JSON opposite. First it was an array then all objects.

Comment: Hey, if the ansewer helped, you can go on and accept it so other will people will know that your issue is resolved.